# VBA Code to copy & paste ranges of data from one sheet to another based on date (as criteria)

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded the following macro and then edited the code to include a condition, but the code is not working as it is. And when I remove the 2nd IF argument the data is copied in all columns in the distination sheet. Wereas my objective is to copy the data only if the date in the columns headers are matching. Basically I values in sheet "Daily Input Form" in a simple tab and I want to have it copied in the "Daily Cash Flow" sheet (which has multiple columns) only if the date in the header of specific column matches the date in the "Daily Input Form" sheet...(which is simply the formula "Today()".

I know there is a much simpler way to write the code but I'm a novis to the VBA, so appreciate if you can help me out.

Thanks

```
Sub RangeCopy1()
'
' RangeCopy1 Macro

    Dim lRow As Range, Cell As Object
    Set lRow = Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Range("E13:AV13")
    For Each Cell In lRow


        If Cell.Value = "YES" Then

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("D7:D12").Select
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E36:AV36").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("D15:D25").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E43:AV43").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("D28:D34").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E56:AV56").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("H7:H23").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E68:AV68").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("H26:H63").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E86:AV86").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

           Sheets("Daily Input Form").Select
           Range("H66:H86").Select
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Daily Cash Flow").Select
           Range("E125:AV125").Select
           Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False



           Application.CutCopyMode = False




        End If

            If Cell.Value = "" Then

                Exit Sub


            End If



    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: You can certainly read up on how to avoid Select which will shorten your code. Which cell needs to be compared with Today() ?

Comment: This is not a code, it is just a machine output, if you want to really do this by VBA, you need to search for similar problems and try to grasp some. It may seem a bit difficult to start, but it is worth it

Comment: SJR, the 2nd sheet "Daily Cash Flow" contain several columns where each column represents one day, the header of each column has the date of that day in it. If you want I can share with you my spreadsheet.

Comment: lbo, I didn't say it was code...I clearly said "I recorded a macro"...